# Eclipse Juno - Constant crash (805306369) when highlighting anything

Tags: java, eclipse-juno

Whenever I mouse over any imported.. anything in Juno, Eclipse immediately hangs.

Editing Java files - types, classes, annotations, the import itself - mousing over anything to view the javadoc will instantly hang eclipse.
Also happens with auto-completes if the popup stays open for more than a second.

Here's the error:
[image: Juno Error 805306369]

Running:

```
java version "1.7.0_15"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_15-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

The latest Eclipse Juno (Java EE) 64bit
Win7 x64.

There shouldn't be any incompatibilities there (All x64).

Looking around the proposed fixes are either related to Java 6, or say to delete `Mylyn`, which I've done but no fix.

This error happens consistently every single time.

Edit:
And to make things more annoying, the log in the .metadata folder is empty.
I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious as the *exact same setup* on my other laptop works fine. And searching just gets me unreadable mailing lists, or bug trackers saying it's fixed - when clearly it's not in this case.

Comment: Since you mention this does not happen on another laptop computer of yours, some wild guess: I saw this similar issues on Linux with older versions of Eclipse. There it was related Eclipse using a web browser library to render tool tips. On some of Linux setups that resulted in crashes. There would be a crash dump that indicated xulrunner as part of the issue. Your example is different: Windows, and a much newer version of Eclipse. Still, maybe the difference between your laptop computer where all is fine and the problematic computer is also in the available web browsers on those systems?

Comment: Possibly, but both computers are Win7 x64, same java version, and newest Juno.

Comment: Since you're on an `x64` Windows, the Eclipse launcher uses `-arch x86_64`. Your Java runtime seems to be from `c:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe`. Is that a true 64 bit Java runtime? Maybe check via Help/About/Installation Details/Configuration which `java.home` is really used, look for things like `java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`
 and `sun.arch.data.model=64` to verify that it's running as 64 bit. And compare those values between your two computers, the one where it all works and where it doesn't.

Comment: It's definitely x64 java (I've removed all others and the ones in sys32, then installed just one version to be sure). I'll check the java home variables between to check differences.

Comment: Ok, I've checked the Java Home variable and it was different - corrected it to point where it should. Still getting the exact same crash though =/. The other variables (vm name, sun arch model) are both 64 bit as well and the same between both computers

Comment: Just to add if anyone's viewing - still occurring.

Comment: i don't know if you still have this problem, but i was able to get rid of it. see the answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Warning**: *the solution described below corrected the problem on my computer, but the problem may not be the same on your computer... YMMV.*

So, the incriminated popups are displaying an HTML snippet. This snippet is rendered using *mshtml.dll*.

The same *mshtml.dll* is used to render HTML Help files (files with extension *.chm*). On my computer, i discovered that i was not able to open any HTML Help file: the HTML Help Executable (*hh.exe*) was crashing at launch.

After some more research (i won't go through all the details of the search), it appeared that the drivers for my display adapter, which is an nVidia GeForce 540M, were at fault. They were outdated, and their installation got probably corrupted.

After updating the drivers, the system was back to normal: i can open HTML Help files again, and Eclipse is no more crashing when displaying those little HTML filled popups !

So, the first step for you would be to check that you can open an HTML Help file correctly. Then you should check your display adapter driver installation... If it does not solve your problem, there can be many reasons for mshtml.dll file to crash, try to make something using mshtml.dll crash: this crash might give you more information than when eclipse brutally exits.

(note that the corrupted drivers prevented the execution of the standard driver installer package downloaded from nVidia. I had to go to the device manager, open the properties for my display adapter, then click the "update driver" button. everything went smoothly, and automatically, from there)

(note also that my system is running Windows 7 64-bit)

Comment: Thanks so much! Wasn't my display adaptor, but my mshtml or hh file was corrupted it seems - getting that repaired (`SFC /SCANNOW` actually ended up doing the job) worked a treat!. Now to remember what I was originally trying to code...

Comment: After 6 hours of cleaning workspaces, reinstalling java and eclipse I found this answer. In fact it was the hh.exe but none of the above worked for me. So I deleted my Windows user Profile and created a new one. That fixed the problem. Ughhh this was a weired thing. Thank you

Answer (score 12):

After many many permutations of everything, including all the different JDK's etc etc ..

This worked for me (Fedora19/64, ADT 4.3/SDK 22.x,OpenJDK 1.8, Opteron64):  add this line to the `eclipse.ini` file

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

apparantly the tooltip bits launch different browsers at different times with "collisions", but retricting to mozilla only seems to do the trick

found it here (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1163501)

Comment: this resolved issue for my ubuntu pc, i tested the symptom using another answer

Comment: This solved my problem with Mulesoft AnypointStudio on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

> ```
> export WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1
> ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).