# Eclipse Keeps Crashing Upon Typing "." For Python. Exit Code= -805306369

Tags: python, eclipse, crash, exit, typing

Basically whenever I type the character `"."` for a method, eclipse freezes and crashes. The error code I get back is `exit code= -805306369`. I have tried creating a new workspace and uninstalling eclipse and java, but nothing works. Please help!

Comment: Have a look at answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968580/eclipse-juno-constant-crash-805306369-when-highlighting-anything